# MVC Pass IDs from view to controller from checkbox multiselection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

At the moment i have a table with a column fill with checkbox for each ID user. and i want to pass that value from checkbox checked from view to controller to perfom some action in actionresult CreatePlanning. 
How can i do it ?

```
<td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status_Coordinator)">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Status_Coordinator)
                    <input id="Status_Coordinator" type="checkbox" name="Status_Coordinator" value="true" />
                </td>
```

Comment: You could pass it via ajax or a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably other ways to do this, but I have done it like this previously - Create a new Checkbox class like:

```
public class CheckboxModel
{
    //Value of checkbox 
    public int Value { get; set; }
    //description of checkbox 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    //whether the checkbox is selected or not
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Initialise static list of users, to give you an idea (you probably have to generate it dynamically):

```
ListOfUserID = new List<CheckboxModel>
               { 
                  new CheckboxModel { Value = 1, Text = "User1" },
                  new CheckboxModel { Value = 2, Text = "User2" },
                  new CheckboxModel { Value = 3, Text = "User3" }     
                };
```

Use this class in the view (for example in a loop):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.ListOfUserID[i].IsChecked)@Model.ListOfUserID[i].Text
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ListOfUserID[i].Value)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ListOfUserID[i].Text)
```

Then you have the text or value of the checkbox in Controller action when the form is posted.

Answer (score 0):

To select use Checkboxfor
`

#### Select your Order:

@foreach (var x in Model)
{
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => x.isSelected, new { @id="test"
,value = (x.Orderumber) })
}
Get Values

To pass value To the controller use JQuery as:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#b1").click(function () {
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input[name='x.isSelected']:checked"), function () {
            favorite.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("Your order are: " + favorite.join(", "));
        window.location.replace("https://localhost:44304/SecondPage/? 
       id="+favorite.join(", "));
          });
        });
       </script>
```